# Issue in exposing docker containers

Tags: python, docker, networking, containers, port

I have the following code sending client to the server and retrieving the result from the server.
I have a firewall machine and my machine (server) is behind a firewall - I am connecting to the port 22 (ssh) on server machine on port 22238 on a firewall machine. I have redirected port 5555 on firewall machine to port 5555 on the machine (server). My issue is I am unable to send the data from the client to the server using socket interface.

I am running a client and server in a docker container

server docker container

```
 docker run --rm -it -p 192.168.xx.xx8:5555:5555 server bash
```

client docker container

```
 docker run --rm -it -p 192.168.xx.xx0:5555:5555 client bash

context=zmq.Context()
socket=context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:5555")
while True:
 message=socket.recv_pyobj()
 print("%s:%s" %(message.get(1)[0],message.get(1)[1]))
 socket.send_pyobj({1:[message.get(1)[0],message.get(1)[1]]})
```

server.py

```
context=zmq.Context()
print("Connecting")
socket=context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://192.168.xx.xx8:5555")
name="Max"
while True:
  message=input("Message: ")
  socket.send_pyobj({1:[name,message]})
  message2=socket.recv_pyobj()
  print("%s:%s" %(message2.get (1)[0], message2.get(1)[1]))
```

Thanks help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just for your info, xxxing out addresses on your local network isn't going to make you more or less vulnerable to attacks, but it makes your question less readable. Anyhow, please reduce your setup to something resembling a [mcve], so that you can say exactly at which point things fail and what is the setup that causes this. In case you haven't, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the "client" and "server" scripts. Does the message interchange work if you simply run them in separate shells (not in containers)?

Does your dockerfile define ENTRYPOINT? If it only defines CMD, I think you have replaced CMD with `bash` and only get the bash process in the container, not your client/server executables.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this and will update you @SamR, and haven't defined entry-point in the docker file.